# Eval() isn't executed in Chrome when using Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy

When using the report-only mode of the *Content-Security-Policy*, Chrome does not execute `eval()` anymore.

For the following example, I would expect to get 2 reports (one for the inline-script and one for the `eval`) and also, to see a pop-up. But only the 2 reports are displayed in the console.

Do I use the CSP wrong or is there a bug with the CSP report-only mode in Chrome?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only"   content="default-src 'self'; report-uri /dummy.html"/>     
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only" content="default-src 'self'; report-uri /dummy.html"/>     
    <meta http-equiv="X-WebKit-CSP-Report-Only"              content="default-src 'self'; report-uri /dummy.html"/>
    <head>
        <script>
            eval('alert(1);');  
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can replicate this, and I've filed https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=111867. I'll have a fix in shortly. It's straightforward oversight on my part. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi Mike, I tried this again with Chrome27 (27.0.1453.93m) and things are slightly better: eval() is now executed in report-only mode - but no longer reported in the console.